# In Perl, how can I use the regex substitution operator to replace non-ASCII characters in a substring?

Tags: regex, perl

How to use this command:

```
perl -pi -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]/#/g' file
```

to change only characters at offset A to offset B of each line?

Comment: Some example actual and expected data would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively to rubber boots' answer, you can operate on a substring instead of the whole string to begin with:

```
perl -pi -e 'substr($_, 5, 5) =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]/#/g' file
```

To illustrate:

```
perl -e 'print "\xff" x 16' | \
perl -p -e 'substr($_, 5, 5) =~ s/[^[:ascii:]]/#/g' | \
hd
```

will print

```
ff ff ff ff ff 23 23 23  23 23 ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

In this code, the first offset is 0-based, and you have to use the length instead of the second offset, so it will be
`substr($_, A-1, B-A)`.

Answer (score 7):

Under reservation that I didn't understand your question correctly, if the offsets A, and B are 5 and 10, then it should be like:

```
  perl -pi -e 's/(?<=.{5})(?<!.{10})[^[:ascii:]]/#/g' file
```

Explanation:

```
   [^[:ascii:]]  <- the character which is looked for
   (?<=.{5})     <- if at least 5 chars were before (offset 5)
   (?<!.{10})    <- but no more than 10 characters before (offset 10)
```

The constructs:

```
   (?<= ...) and (?<! ...)
```

are called *positive and negative lookbehinds*, which are *zero-with assertions*.
(You can google them, see section [Look-Around Assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns))

---

**Addendum 1** 
You mentioned `substr()` in your title, which I overlooked first. This would work, of course, too:

```
  perl -pi -e 'substr($_,5,10)=~s/[^[:ascii:]]/#/g' file
```

The description of `substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH` can be [found in perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html).
This example nicely illustrates the use of `substr()` as a left-value.

---

**Addendum 2**
When updating this post, [Grrrr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241849/170194) added the same solution as an answer, but his came first by a minute! <sup>(so he deserves the booty)</sup>

Regards

rbo

Comment: I did not notice "with substr" in the title either, or rather, interpreted it as "within a substring", so I think your solution is no less valid than mine...